# How do I find the intervals where the function is increasing with variables?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

I am confused on how to to this question. Do I find the derivative and the critical points in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes. Find the values of $x$ for which $f'(x)>0$.

Comment: So I found that x < the square root of b/a. Does this seem correct? If so then how do I know what the intervals are?

Comment: Oh wait I think I got it thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure it is $x<\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$? Anyway $x<c$ corresponds to $x\in(-\infty,c)$. Similarly $x>c$ corresponds to $x\in(c,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Compute $$f'(x)=a-\frac{b}{x^2}$$ and solve the inequalities $$f'(x)>0$$ or $$f'(x)<0$$ for $x$. For increasing you will need only $$f'(x)>0$$
You will get $$a>\frac{b}{x^2}$$ which is possible, since we have $a>0$

Comment: Wouldn’t the A be positive in the derivative?

Comment: I think there is a typo, he/she meant decreasing

Comment: When you found the derivative of the function f, you put -a. Isn’t that suppose to be positive a in the derivative?

Comment: Yes it is, it was a simple typo